# ¿Cómo manejan los servlets la llamada de métodos de otros objetos?

Tags: java, servlets, hibernate, hilos

Estoy con un proyecto web (una aplicación web de Java). Les cuento mas o menos lo que tengo.
Hay un servlet que llama a un método de un objeto (previamente este objeto es recuperado desde la base de datos). Dentro del método del objeto se produce una llamada a otro método de otro objeto, el cual hace modificación sobre un atributo de instancia de si mismo.
Aquí les dejo un código que explica lo que quiero decir arriba.

```
public void addElemento(Elemento unElemento) throws ElementoException {
    if (tengo(Elemento)) {
        throw new ElementoException("El elemento ya está en la lista");
    }
    unElemento.addAlgo(new Algo("parametro"));
    this.elementos.add(unElemento);
}
```

El asunto está en el método `addAlgo`

```
public void addAlgo(Algo unAlgo){
    this.algos.add(unAlgo);
    synchronized (this) {
        this.setValor(this.getValor() + 1);
    }
}
```

¿Es correcto que ponga un bloque sincronizado para modificar el valor de un atributo de un objeto?
No estoy seguro del todo de como trabajar los servlets (si son thread-safe o no) ya que he visto diversas fuentes y hay gente que dice que sí y gente que dice que no.

Mi duda viene porque es obvio que un servlet puede ser ejecutado por uno, por dos o incluso por cien usuarios y puede darse el caso en el que varias ejecuciones sucedan al mismo tiempo. Sí, sé que es difícil pero todos sabemos que puede pasar, así que es mejor estar preparados.

¿Es necesario sincronizar los bloques en donde se producen modificaciones de datos o el contenedor de servlets se encarga de esto?

P.D.: Aunque no está expresado en el código de ejemplo que puse, luego de modificar los valores, estos cambios son reflejados en la base de datos.

---

Primero me disculpo por la ambigüedad de la pregunta ya que es muy genérica y nada específica. Segundo y algo muy importante que he olvidado comentar, **estoy utilizando Hibernate** para persistir los objetos en la base de datos.

Tengo una tienda que tiene un stock y varios artículos para la venta.
Como se imaginarán, cada instancia de una línea de stock conoce a un artículo.

La tienda a su vez tiene muchos usuarios y estos pueden hacer reservas sobre los artículos. El problema vendría ahí, supongamos que sale un artículo nuevo y todo el mundo quiere reservarlo.

Al momento de clickear en el link que llama al servlet encargado de crear una reserva, asignarla a un cliente y **decrementar el stock para ese artículo** (todo esto mediante injección de dependencia), si se ejecuta la acción al mismo tiempo puede darse el mencionado **java.lang.ConcurrentModificationException**.

Les dejo el código en el que se produce el decremento del stock (esto pasa en la instancia de la clase Artículo)

```
public void addReserva(Reserva unaReserva) {
        ArticuloReserva articuloReserva = new ArticuloReserva(this, unaReserva);
        this.reservas.add(articuloReserva);
        this.getStock().setCantidad(this.getStock().getCantidad() - 1);
        HibernateUtil.actualizar(this);
    }
```

**EDITADA 2**
Código de HibernateUtil#actualizar()

```
public static void actualizar(Object unObjeto) throws HibernateException { 
    Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    session.merge(unObjeto);
    transaction.commit();
    session.close();

}
```

El HibernateUtil#getSessionFactory viene de la clase helper creada por Hibernate:

```
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            // loads configuration and mappings
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();

            // builds a session factory from the service registry
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);           
        }

        return sessionFactory;
    }
```

Stacktrace de cuando se produce un java.lang.ConcurrentModificationException.

```
Advertencia:   StandardWrapperValve[ReservarArticuloServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet ReservarArticuloServlet threw exception
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$IteratorProxy.next(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:774)
    at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.replaceElements(CollectionType.java:549)
    at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.replace(CollectionType.java:690)
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.replace(TypeHelper.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.copyValues(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:372)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:309)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:872)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:854)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:859)
    at com.herokuapp.apptienda.util.HibernateUtil.actualizar(HibernateUtil.java:53)
    at com.herokuapp.apptienda.modelo.Articulo.addReserva(Articulo.java:153)
    at com.herokuapp.apptienda.modelo.Tienda.addReserva(Tienda.java:363)
    at com.herokuapp.apptienda.servlet.articulo.ReservarArticuloServlet.doGet(ReservarArticuloServlet.java:55)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Debes recordar que el servlet container crea una instancia de tu servlet por cada request, el problema viene cuando en tu servlet declaras una variable de instancia (atributo) ya que este atributo no será `thread-safe`, para tu ejemplo veo que el problema estaría en intentar insertar el mismo registro por 2 request diferentes, según tu escenario de producción ¿es esto posible? Realiza pruebas de ello usa JMeter y sal de las dudas.

Comment: Por favor provee el código de `HibernateUtil#actualizar`. Algo me dice que allí es donde está tu problema, puede ser que tienes todos los elementos para la interacción con base de datos de manera estática y reutilizados para todos tus ciclos request/response en lugar de tenerlos instanciados uno a uno por ciclo. De ser así, tengo alternativas de solución para tu caso.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Disculpen si era obvio incluir esa información y no la he puesto en la pregunta. De todos modos ahí está, cualquier otra cosa que necesiten para responder la pregunta lo agrego.

Comment: ¿Podrías también agregar el stacktrace cuando te aparece el `ConcurrentModificationException`?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Listo señor. He revisado el stacktrace varias veces y el error ocurre en `Articulo#addReserva` en donde se llama a `HibernateUtil#actualizar`. Si el problema está ahí no sé como resolverlo, pues el valor del stock del artículo debe ser actualizado.

Answer (score 1):

Tal como Rosendo Ropher me recomendó, he estado probando JMeter. Es una herramienta fabulosa para probar casos de concurrencia a datos (y eso es sólo una de las cosas que ofrece).

Cómo he comentado, puede darse el caso que varios usuarios ejecuten el método `addElemento`. Así que decidí lanzar 10 hilos con JMeter para probar el acceso concurrente sobre un mismo dato (el parámetro `unElemento` pasado al método `addElemento`).

Cada hilo se "logueaba" con datos de distintos usuarios (usuario y contraseña) y al momento de que cada uno llamaba al método `addElemento` se producía un `java.lang.ConcurrentModificationException`.

Luego de sincronizar bloques internos en donde se poducía la modificación y obtener el mismo resultado vi el problema desde otra perspectiva y empecé a hacer tests sincronizados bloques y métodos (usando la palabra clave `synchronized`) en capas superiores del hilo de ejecución en donde se producía la excepción.

**Conclusión:**
He añadido la palabra clave `synchronized` al método `addElemento` y la excepción no se volvió a producir.

```
public void addElemento(Elemento unElemento) throws ElementoException {
       if (tengo(Elemento)) {
           throw new ElementoException("El elemento ya está en la lista");
       }
       unElemento.addAlgo(new Algo("parametro"));
       this.elementos.add(
}
```

Comment: En lugar de malusar `synchronized` y ralentizar tu aplicación, te recomiendo dos cosas: o bien utilizas `AtomicInteger` o `AtomicLong` que soporta la funcionalidad que quieres mediante el método `incrementAndGet` o dejas que tu fuente de datos incremente ese valor por ti, de manera que tu aplicación es libre de ese tipo de cosas. Ahora, sería mejor si explicaras qué es lo que realmente necesitas hacer, esto parece más como si tu aplicación manejara los auto increment de la base de datos cuando la bd puede hacer esto mejor y sin problemas.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Gracias por tu respuesta. Tienes razón en que la aplicación manejara lo que la BD debería hacer y se que eso está **mal**. Tampoco conocía esas clases de Java que mencionas y mucho menos su utilidad (uno nunca deja de aprender). Fíjate que he añadido más detalles en la pregunta. Según lo que me dices me conviene hacer que el decremento de stock suceda en la capa de datos. Traducido a lo que estoy haciendo, pienso que implementar un trigger con Hibernate podria funcionar. Mientras espero comentarios o respuestas sigo con otra cosa. Si llego a probar lo que les digo les cuento.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando utilizas una variable de instancia, por ejemplo

```
public class Algo extends HttpServlet {
    //algoMas no es thread-safe
    private String algoMas = "";

    ...
}
```

es donde tienes que preocuparte por la sincronización, ya que si `algoMas` debe tomar un valor de acuerdo a algún flujo de ejecución de tu usuario (request) el resultado final seguramente no será el esperado o el correcto.

Por lo anterior, se tienen 3 soluciones

1. Evita las variables de instancia y definelas dentro de los métodos `doGet` o `doPost` según sea el caso
2. Sincronización parcial, si es necesario que utilices una variable de instancia entonces (la respuesta a tu pregunta es) si debes sincronizar aquellos bloques de código que pueden representar un conflicto en una multiejecución, siempre tomando en cuenta que sincronizas el código necesario y no involucres en ello rutinas que no deben ser sincronizadas.
3. Sincronización completa, puedes implementar una interface como `SingleThreadModel (*deprecated*)`, la parte negativa de esto es que el servlet container no permitirá que tu servlet sea ejecutado simultáneamente y eso no es lo que se desea o no es lo que se espera de una web app.

Puedes leer un buen artículo sobre ello [aquí](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2072798/java-web-development/write-thread-safe-servlets.html)

Comment: No he definido variables de instancia en ningún servlet. Todas las variables que he definido están dentro de los métodos doGet y doPost. La variable que me preocupa como es accedida y modificada corresponde a una instancia clase del modelo de datos. En fin, voy a probar como me va con JMeter y te comentaré. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Sobre el punto 1, diría que depende. Las variables de instancia son buenas siempre y cuando sean stateless (es decir, no mantienen estado). Sobre los puntos 2 y 3, diría que se debería evitar la sincronización en las aplicaciones Web de ser posible y solo agregar `sinchronized` o trabajar con `Lock` si es estrictamente necesario, lo cual lo dudo de una aplicación Web, no es que sea un ESB o un Cache Manager o alguna otra tecnología que deba tener este tipo de mecanismos, sus operaciones deberían ser casi siempre atómicas.

Comment: Acabo de revisar el artículo que compartes, y ese problema bien se puede resolver con `AtomicInteger`. O mejor aún: no utilizar variables que sabes que van a ser compartidas por diversos hilos. En lo personal, me agrada más la explicación de BalusC (experto en Java SE y Java EE) de [aquí](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3106909/1065197).